# Is there a way where i can subtract a value from database and input type text number?

Tags: codeigniter

[image: In this image, I have a current wallet which is from the DB. Your bet which is from the input type number. And a remaining balance where it shows the difference of the 2 fields.]

**The input type text from the views:**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="uname" id="box" required>
```

**The modal content from the views:**

```
 <p>YOUR BET:  <a class="p-1" id="betAmountResult"></a></p>
        <p>CURRENT WALLET:   <a style="color:blue;"><?php echo $_SESSION['currentWallet']?></a></p>
    
        <p class="remaining">REMAINING BALANCE:
         
          <a class="p-1" id="betAmountResult"></a></p>
```

Comment: show us your code to calculate `REMAINING BALANCE:`.

Comment: I'm constructing a pseudo code but I still don't have the idea about how to convert it into codes. If so, may I ask for your suggestion? 

I'm studying this one: https://prnt.sc/w27pbq  <<< But this one is kinda advance. I'm just beginner and i'm simplifying this advance code into simpler ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="uname" id="box" required>

  <p>YOUR BET:  <a class="p-1" id="betAmount"></a></p>
  <!-- change id's name to betAmount -->
    <p>CURRENT WALLET:   <a style="color:blue;"><?php echo $_SESSION['currentWallet']?></a></p>

    <p class="remaining">REMAINING BALANCE:
     
      <a class="p-1" id="betAmountResult"></a></p>



  <script>

     $( document ).ready(function() {
     
        $("#box").keyup( function(){
             var betAmount = $("#box").val();
             var walletAmount = <?php echo $_SESSION['currentWallet']?>;

             var remainingAmount = walletAmount - betAmount;


            $("#betAmountResult").text(remainingAmount);
        })
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Sadly, it's not working. It is not showing the result. :/

Comment: Hey Dark!! May be the result is not showing because of missing document.ready function. I've edited this answer please try it out.

Comment: Ty for helping. But it's not working. :/     prnt.sc/w2akhl <<< Screenshot

Comment: Hey Dark!! Every element in html have unique id, you cannot create two Ids with same name ('betAmountResult" in your code).

Comment: And make sure you've added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in your head section.

Comment: Hello, i did all your suggestions, but it's not really working. See the screenshot. 

https://prnt.sc/w2wg88

Comment: Thank you so much @yuvraj. Works like a magic.